# Convert ResponseEntity<Any> to a List<ObjectNode> [Kotlin]

Tags: json, kotlin

I have a method returning a `ResponseEntity<Any>` and taking a payload, which is of type `ObjectNode`. I am trying to do the following, but the cast is not correct:

```
val objectNodeList = responseEntity.body as List<ObjectNode>
```

How do you convert a `ResponseEntity<Any>` to a `List<ObjectNode>`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `responseEntity.body` is of type `ObjectNode`, then you can't cast it safely to anything else than that. If you really want a list from it, you can just make a simple list of one element with it:

```kotlin
val objectNodeList = listOf(responseEntity.body as ObjectNode)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have an additional question to ask. I have identified that the <Any> part is actually a dto in my implementation, which is fine. I have a for loop after 

```val listDto = listOf(responseEntity.body as MyDto)```

which is as follows: 

```for (element in listDto) { //some code }```

The issue is that I am returned with a cast error whereby ```class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class MyDto``` Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @paranza it all comes down to the actual type of the thing you are trying to cast. Casting is not converting, it is just telling the compiler that you know the actual type better than it does. Given the error you have, it really seems that the thing you're casting is actually an `ArrayList`, so the cast to the `List<MyDto>` should work in the first place. It would be nice to have a bit more context to help more.

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes I will go out and  try a few things, in case I will open another question if the issue persists. It puzzles me that I cannot iterate through a ```List<MyDto>```, but perhaps I am missing something here.